# Foreach PHP PDO query

Tags: php, foreach, pdo

I this PHP foreach code properly written?

```
$colors = $_GET['color'];
$i = 0;
foreach (explode(' ', $colors) as $color) 
{
    $items = $con -> prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
    $items -> bindValue(":colorbase1", $color[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

I cannot get the SQL to work.

Comment: You don't seem to be running your query....

Comment: `I am wondering, is this FOREACH properly written?` depends on what you want to do? Also why are you accessing color as an array?

Comment: It's better practice to store the array as an array, then loop through it, rather than by reference: `$colorsArr = explode(" ", $colors); foreach($colorsArr as $color) { ... }`

Comment: it's not wrong by PHP parsing rules, but it's not going to do what you want, so by that measure, it's flat-out wrong.

Comment: btw, you shouldn't prepare it every time. You may use 1 prepare statement to a number of queries

Comment: You don't need the $i in foreach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do what you're asking - you're generating `$color` as a variable in the foreach, but you were accessing it as an array.

```
$colors = explode(' ', $_GET['color']);
foreach ($colors as $color) 
{
    $items = $con -> prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
    $items -> bindValue(":colorbase1", $color);
}
```

Comment: Will this call explode() on each pass, or just once?

Comment: @Erty - just once, I think; I've just run a quick test, and it only seems to call it the once.

Comment: @Erty - though as Matt mentions above, it's better practice to initialise it outside the loop.